# Форматирование строк в C++

Tags: c++, строки

Мне нужно собрать строку типа: 'unzip -P 123456 file.zip' из двух string и одного int. Мой код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string out;
    string s1 = "unzip -P ";
    string s2 = " file.zip";
    int pass = 123456;
    out = s1 << to_string(pass) << s2;
    cout << out << endl;
    return 0;
};
```

При компиляции происходят две ошибки:

```
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:691:5: ошибка: нет имени типа «type» в «struct std::enable_if<false, void>»

myfile.cpp:9:14: ошибка: no match for «operator<<» (operand types are «std::string» {aka «std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>»} and «std::string» {aka «std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>»})
```

Почему так происходит? Я неправильно складываю строки? Есть другой способ?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `out = s1 + string(pass) + s2`

Comment: @Harry Кстати, есть ли разница между `to_string(1)` и `string(1)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ваш код:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string out;
    string s1 = "unzip -P ";
    string s2 = " file.zip";
    int pass = 123456;
    out = s1 << to_string(pass) << s2;
    cout << out << endl;
    return 0;
};
```

**Исправленный код:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string out;
    string s1 = "unzip -P ";
    string s2 = " file.zip";
    int pass = 123456;
    out = s1 + to_string(pass) + s2;
    cout << out << endl;
    return 0;
};
```

***Ошибки:***
 1. Вы не подключили библиотеку `<string>`. Она предназначена для работы со строками в C++.

2. В этой строке out = *s1 << to_string(pass) << s2;* вы используете неверный оператор <<, тогда как необходимо использовать '+'

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант №1**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string out;
    string s1 = "unzip -P ";
    string s2 = " file.zip";
    int pass = 123456;
    out = s1 + to_string(pass) + s2;
    cout << out << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Вариант №2**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string out;
    stringstream ss;
    int pass = 123456;

    string s1 = "unzip -P ";
    string s2 = " file.zip";


    ss << s1 << to_string(pass) << s2;
    out = ss.str().c_str();

    cout << out << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Вариант 3**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int pass = 123456;
    string s1 = "unzip -P";
    string s2 = "file.zip";

    char buff[100];

    sprintf_s(buff, sizeof(buff), "%s %d %s", s1.c_str(), pass, s2.c_str());

    string out = buff;

    cout << out << endl;

    return 0;
}
```